# An Accurate Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, timer

I've been trying to make an accurate JavaScript timer using Backbone JS this is as far as I've gotten:

[Source Code](http://jsbin.com/UnUBUrOX/5/edit)

It works apart from the the complete event fires twice when it shouldn't, any ideas on what I need to do to fix/improve it?

Console Output:

```
"tick 10 1"
"tick 10 2"
"tick 10 3"
"tick 10 4"
"tick 10 5"
"tick 10 6"
"tick 10 7"
"tick 10 8"
"tick 10 9"
"complete 10 10"
"complete 10 11"
```

Comment: Put your code in your question.

Comment: Looks like you call start twice if I am reading it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `start` twice, once in your `TimerView.initialize` and once again after you instantiate it, meaning you have two concurrent `setTimeout` loops occurring (and, you're timer is moving twice as fast):

```
var Timer = Backbone.Model.extend({
  /* ... */
});

var TimerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  /* ... */
  initialize: function () {
    this.model.on('tick', function(e){console.log('tick '+e.steps+' '+e.count);}, this);
    this.model.on('complete', function(e){console.log('complete '+e.steps+' '+e.count);}, this);
    this.model.start(); // <-- One here
  }
});

var timer = new Timer();
var timerView = new TimerView({model: timer});
timer.start();  // <-- Another here
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `start()` twice. Once after creating the model and view, and once inside your view initialize function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var TimerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Timer,
    tagName: 'p',
    className: 'timer',
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('tick', function(e){console.log('tick '+e.steps+' '+e.count);}, this);
        this.model.on('complete', function(e){console.log('complete '+e.steps+' '+e.count);}, this);
        /* this.model.start(); - don't need this */
    }
});
```